# Dygraph display X-axis at the top of the figure

Tags: dygraphs

I want my X-axis to be at the top of the figure along with the axisLabels and my Y-axis to be invisible as described below.How can it done ?

```
1     2       3       4
+-----+-------+-------+------+
|
|
|
|
|
|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no simple way to move the x-axis to the top without mucking with `plugins/axes.js`.

To hide the y-axis, you can use the [`drawAxis` option](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#drawAxis):

```
g = new Dygraph(div, data, {
  axes: {
    y: {
      drawAxis: false
    }
  }
});
```